# Migrated php files from a server with php 5.1.6 to one with 5.3.3

Tags: php, syntax

Hey guys so I had everything working perfectly on my old server with php 5.1.6 I had this script:

```
<? session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<?
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
print $name;
if (empty($name)){
print "
<link rel=stylesheet href=css/screen2.css media=screen />
<form id=contactform class=rounded method=post action=panelBackend.php>
<h3>Login</h3>

<div class=field>
<label for=name>Username:</label>
<input type=text class=input name=name id=name />
<p class=hint>Minecraft Username.</p>
</div>

<div class=field>
<label for=password>Password:</label>
<input type=password class=input name=password id=password />
<p class=hint>Free Minecraft Host Password.</p>
</div>

<input type=submit name=Login  class=button value=Login />
</form>";
} else {
header( 'Location: http://x.x.x.x/panelBackend.php' );
}
?>
```

And before it worked fine! Now when I goto it i get the form WITHOUT the style, and it prints out this php code at the bottom:

```
"; } else { header( 'Location: http://69.64.80.200/panelBackend.php' ); } ?>
```

Is there something that different in the PHP versions?

Comment: First, please please quote your html attribute values. Second, use a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The new one doesn't have short tags enabled. Change all `<?` to `<?php`.